How to remove and move several puzzle pieces?
Based on the code https://texample.net/tikz/examples/puzzle/ by Marc van Dongen (all credits to @Marc van Dongen) I would like to develop a picture in which some puzzle pieces are removed from a picture and collected under the picture:
%https://texample.net/tikz/examples/puzzle/
%Author: Marc van Dongen
\documentclass[12pt]{article}       

%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>


\begin{comment}
:Title: Puzzle
:Tags: Clipping, Paths
:Author: Marc van Dongen

This tikz example display a puzzle with a text inside.

\end{comment}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}

\makeatletter

\newif\ifpuzzle@hole
\newif\ifpuzzle@hole@A
\newif\ifpuzzle@hole@B
\newif\ifpuzzle@hole@C
\newif\ifpuzzle@hole@D
\def\puzzle@width{0.25cm}
\def\puzzle@height{0.20cm}
\def\puzzle@holes{true,true,false,false}
\def\puzzle@set@hole@A#1,#2,#3,#4,{\csname puzzle@hole@A#1\endcsname}
\def\puzzle@set@hole@B#1,#2,#3,#4,{\csname puzzle@hole@B#2\endcsname}
\def\puzzle@set@hole@C#1,#2,#3,#4,{\csname puzzle@hole@C#3\endcsname}
\def\puzzle@set@hole@D#1,#2,#3,#4,{\csname puzzle@hole@D#4\endcsname}
\pgfkeys{/puzzle/width/.store in=\puzzle@width}                      
\pgfkeys{/puzzle/height/.store in=\puzzle@height}                    
\pgfkeys{/puzzle/holes/.store in=\puzzle@holes}                      

\def\Photography{
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2} {
        \foreach \y in {1,2} {
            \draw[puzzle piece,thick] (1.5*\x,\y) to +(1.5,1.0);
        }                                                                    
    }                                                                        
    \foreach \xy in {1,2} {                                                  
       \draw[puzzle piece,thick] (0,\xy) to +(1.5,1.0);                      
       \draw[puzzle piece,thick] (1.5*\xy,0) to +(1.5,1.0);                  
    } 
                                                                         
    \draw (2.25,1.5) \node {\includegraphics[width=\pagewidth]{example-image-duck}};            
}                                                                            

\def\drawPuzzleSide#1#2#3{%
    let \p{mid}=($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$),
        \p{diff}=($(#2)-(#1)$),   
        \p{diff 90}=($(0,0)!1.0!\csname ifpuzzle@hole@#3\endcsname90\else270\fi:(\p{diff})$),                                                                   
        \n{len}={veclen(\x{diff},\y{diff})},                                    
        \n{height}={\puzzle@height},                                            
        \n{width}={\puzzle@width},                                              
        \p{dy}=($(\n{height}*\x{diff 90}/\n{len},\n{height}*\y{diff 90}/\n{len})$),                                                                             
        \p{dx}=($(\n{width}*\x{diff}/\n{len},\n{width}*\y{diff}/\n{len})$),     
        \p{xx}=($(\p{diff})-(\p{dx})$),                                         
        \p{11}=($(#1)+0.20*(\p{xx})-0.020*(\p{diff 90})$),                      
        \p{12}=($(#1)+0.35*(\p{xx})-0.030*(\p{diff 90})$),                      
        \p{13}=($(\p{mid})-0.5*(\p{dx})-0.030*(\p{diff 90})$),                  
        \p{21}=($(#2)-0.20*(\p{xx})-0.020*(\p{diff 90})$),                      
        \p{22}=($(#2)-0.35*(\p{xx})-0.030*(\p{diff 90})$),                      
        \p{23}=($(\p{mid})+0.5*(\p{dx})-0.030*(\p{diff 90})$),                  
        \p{14}=($(\p{13})+0.60*(\p{dx})+0.80*(\p{dy})$),                        
        \p{24}=($(\p{23})-0.60*(\p{dx})+0.80*(\p{dy})$),                        
        \p{00}=($(\p{mid})+(\p{dy})$),                                          
        \p{15}=($(\p{00})-1.6*(\p{dx})-0.04*(\p{dy})$),                         
        \p{25}=($(\p{15})!2.0!(\p{00})$)                                        
    in .. controls (\p{11}) and (\p{12}) .. (\p{13})                            
       .. controls (\p{14}) and (\p{15}) .. (\p{00})                            
       .. controls (\p{25}) and (\p{24}) .. (\p{23})                            
       .. controls (\p{22}) and (\p{21}) .. (#2)                                
}                                                                               

\def\puzzle@set@holes{%
    \expandafter\puzzle@set@hole@A\puzzle@holes,
    \expandafter\puzzle@set@hole@B\puzzle@holes,
    \expandafter\puzzle@set@hole@C\puzzle@holes,
    \expandafter\puzzle@set@hole@D\puzzle@holes,
}
\def\drawPuzzlePiece{%
   let \p1=(\tikztostart),
       \p2=(\tikztotarget) in
    (\p1) \drawPuzzleSide{\p1}{\p1-|\p2}{A}
          \drawPuzzleSide{\p1-|\p2}{\p2}{B}
          \drawPuzzleSide{\p2}{\p1|-\p2}{C}
          \drawPuzzleSide{\p1|-\p2}{\p1}{D}
}

\tikzset{test/.style={to path={\drawPuzzlePiece}}}
\tikzset{puzzle piece/.style={to path={\drawPuzzlePiece},
                              execute at begin to=\puzzle@set@holes}}

\makeatother

\batchmode

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{scope}[even odd rule]
      \clip (-10,-10) rectangle (5,4)  %beeinflusst den dargestellten Ausschnitt des Gesamtbildes
            {[puzzle piece, rotate=22] (-1,0) to (1.5,2.0)};  %Position herausgenommenes Puzzlestück !?
      \Photography
   \end{scope}
   \draw(-0.1,-9) % neue Lage des herausgenommenen Puzzlestücks
   % herausgenommnes einzelnes Puzzelstück:
         node{\begin{tikzpicture}
                 \clip {[puzzle piece,rotate=22] (-1,0) to (1.5,2)};  %gibt den Inhalt des herausgenommenen Puzzlestücks wieder
                 \draw[puzzle piece] (-3,-1) to (-1.5,0);
                 \Photography
              \end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}

The outcome of the above code is the following:

I would like to add some more "free" puzzle pieces and I would like to add a shadow to the "free" pieces but I am totally lost in how to do this. Can anybody give me a hint on how to expand the code? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

I can't compile this. `! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.
See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...
l.114       \Photography`

@crf: I am using WinEdt and compiled with Lualatex on a Windows 10 machine without any problems. What system do you use?

you cannot ping me if you mispell my username ;). linux. I get the same error with lualatex. you have invalid syntax. if I fix that error, I can compile with lualatex (but not pdflatex). you could have asked your question with the original example, which is far simpler than this. winedit is just an editor as far as I know. your tex distribution might make a difference, as well as compiler, but \draw (coordinate) \node is not valid syntax period.

@cfr : sorry for misspelling your username.

Proof of concept, fix code and make compatible with other engines (as suggested by samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz).

%https://texample.net/tikz/examples/puzzle/
%Author: Marc van Dongen
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}

\makeatletter

\newif\ifpuzzle@hole
\newif\ifpuzzle@hole@A
\newif\ifpuzzle@hole@B
\newif\ifpuzzle@hole@C
\newif\ifpuzzle@hole@D
\def\puzzle@width{0.25cm}
\def\puzzle@height{0.20cm}
\def\puzzle@holes{true,true,false,false}
\def\puzzle@set@hole@A#1,#2,#3,#4,{\csname puzzle@hole@A#1\endcsname}
\def\puzzle@set@hole@B#1,#2,#3,#4,{\csname puzzle@hole@B#2\endcsname}
\def\puzzle@set@hole@C#1,#2,#3,#4,{\csname puzzle@hole@C#3\endcsname}
\def\puzzle@set@hole@D#1,#2,#3,#4,{\csname puzzle@hole@D#4\endcsname}
\pgfkeys{/puzzle/width/.store in=\puzzle@width}
\pgfkeys{/puzzle/height/.store in=\puzzle@height}
\pgfkeys{/puzzle/holes/.store in=\puzzle@holes}

\def\Photography{
  \foreach \x in {0,1,2} {
    \foreach \y in {1,2} {
      \draw[puzzle piece,thick] (1.5*\x,\y) to +(1.5,1.0);
    }
  }
  \foreach \xy in {1,2} {
    \draw[puzzle piece,thick] (0,\xy) to +(1.5,1.0);
    \draw[puzzle piece,thick] (1.5*\xy,0) to +(1.5,1.0);
  }

  \draw (2.25,1.5) node {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}};
}

\def\drawPuzzleSide#1#2#3{%
  let \p{mid}=($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$),
  \p{diff}=($(#2)-(#1)$),
  \p{diff 90}=($(0,0)!1.0!\csname ifpuzzle@hole@#3\endcsname90\else270\fi:(\p{diff})$),
  \n{len}={veclen(\x{diff},\y{diff})},
  \n{height}={\puzzle@height},
  \n{width}={\puzzle@width},
  \p{dy}=($(\n{height}*\x{diff 90}/\n{len},\n{height}*\y{diff 90}/\n{len})$),
  \p{dx}=($(\n{width}*\x{diff}/\n{len},\n{width}*\y{diff}/\n{len})$),
  \p{xx}=($(\p{diff})-(\p{dx})$),
  \p{11}=($(#1)+0.20*(\p{xx})-0.020*(\p{diff 90})$),
  \p{12}=($(#1)+0.35*(\p{xx})-0.030*(\p{diff 90})$),
  \p{13}=($(\p{mid})-0.5*(\p{dx})-0.030*(\p{diff 90})$),
  \p{21}=($(#2)-0.20*(\p{xx})-0.020*(\p{diff 90})$),
  \p{22}=($(#2)-0.35*(\p{xx})-0.030*(\p{diff 90})$),
  \p{23}=($(\p{mid})+0.5*(\p{dx})-0.030*(\p{diff 90})$),
  \p{14}=($(\p{13})+0.60*(\p{dx})+0.80*(\p{dy})$),
  \p{24}=($(\p{23})-0.60*(\p{dx})+0.80*(\p{dy})$),
  \p{00}=($(\p{mid})+(\p{dy})$),
  \p{15}=($(\p{00})-1.6*(\p{dx})-0.04*(\p{dy})$),
  \p{25}=($(\p{15})!2.0!(\p{00})$)
  in .. controls (\p{11}) and (\p{12}) .. (\p{13})
  .. controls (\p{14}) and (\p{15}) .. (\p{00})
  .. controls (\p{25}) and (\p{24}) .. (\p{23})
  .. controls (\p{22}) and (\p{21}) .. (#2)
}

\def\puzzle@set@holes{%
  \expandafter\puzzle@set@hole@A\puzzle@holes,
  \expandafter\puzzle@set@hole@B\puzzle@holes,
  \expandafter\puzzle@set@hole@C\puzzle@holes,
  \expandafter\puzzle@set@hole@D\puzzle@holes,
}
\def\drawPuzzlePiece{%
  let \p1=(\tikztostart),
  \p2=(\tikztotarget) in
  (\p1) \drawPuzzleSide{\p1}{\p1-|\p2}{A}
  \drawPuzzleSide{\p1-|\p2}{\p2}{B}
  \drawPuzzleSide{\p2}{\p1|-\p2}{C}
  \drawPuzzleSide{\p1|-\p2}{\p1}{D}
}

\tikzset{test/.style={to path={\drawPuzzlePiece}}}
\tikzset{puzzle piece/.style={to path={\drawPuzzlePiece},
execute at begin to=\puzzle@set@holes}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[even odd rule]
    \clip (-10,-10) rectangle (5,4)  %beeinflusst den dargestellten Ausschnitt des Gesamtbildes
    [puzzle piece, rotate=22] (-1,0) to (1.5,2.0)
    [puzzle piece, rotate=52] (-2.5,0) to (-1,1)
    ;
    \Photography
  \end{scope}
  \draw(-0.1,-9) % neue Lage des herausgenommenen Puzzlestücks
  node{\begin{tikzpicture}
      \clip {[puzzle piece,rotate=22] (-1,0) to (1.5,2)};
      \draw[puzzle piece] (-3,-1) to (-1.5,0);
      \Photography
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  ;
  \draw (-2.5,-9)
  node{\begin{tikzpicture}
      \clip {[puzzle piece,rotate=52] (-2.5,0) to (-1,1) };
      \draw[puzzle piece] (1,1) to (2.5,2);
      \Photography
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Note: never use \batchmode when debugging and don't use preview unless you are certain it isn't involved (and you shouldn't ever be certain).

maybe \pagewidth -> \paperwidth to make it compilable with other engines as well?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks. I'm not convinced by this now I'm more awake. the second puzzle piece looks wrong to me.
